# Label Text is Not Changing Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to change label text when I press a button, but it does not change. I have this code:

Controler:

```py
class Controller(BoxLayout):
    random_string = StringProperty()
    random_string="hola"
    def do_action(self):
        random_string="h22l"
        print(random_string)
    def do_action2(self):
        random_string="hl2332323"
        print(str(random_string))
```

My `.mk`:

```py
<Controller>:
    label: lvId

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'Click Me'
        on_press: root.do_action()
    
    Button:
        text: 'Click Me'
        on_press: root.do_action2()
    
    Label:
        id: lvId
        text: root.random_string
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the variable through `self`, if you do not, you will be creating a new local variable other than the one you want to access.

```
class Controller(BoxLayout):
    random_string = StringProperty("hola")
    def do_action(self):
        self.random_string="h22l"
        print(self.random_string)
    def do_action2(self):
        self.random_string="hl2332323"
        print(self.random_string)
```

Comment: Thanks it works,and one more thing,if i want to change random_string value from other place like one thread how would i do ? -(sorry for my english )

Comment: @AurelioFernandez 
That depends on how you are implemented, that question is very general that I can not answer without any, so you could create a new question. But before that, I recommend reading about OOP. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. :)